# How to correctly send more than one string using SPI

Tags: c, avr, spi, atmega

I am trying to communicate between two *ATmega* using [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface). First, I initialized SPI for both ATmega. Here ATmega8 is **master** and ATmega32 is **slave**.

---

**MASTER**

Master initialization - ATMEGA8:

```
#define SPI_ddr             DDRB
#define SPI_port            PORTB
#define PIN_sck             5
#define PIN_mosi            3
#define PIN_ss              2
#define PIN_miso            4

#define SPI_PORT_enable()   (SPI_ddr |= (1 << PIN_sck) | (1 << PIN_mosi) | (1 << PIN_ss))
#define CS_High             SPI_port |= (1 << PIN_ss);
#define CS_Low              SPI_port &= ~(1 << PIN_ss);

void SPI_Init()
{
    SPI_PORT_enable();
    SPI_ddr &= ~(1 << PIN_miso);
    SPCR |= (1 << MSTR) | (1 << SPR0) | (1 << SPR1) | (1 <<SPE);
}
```

---

Functions to send data from master - ATMEGA8:

```
void send_char_SPI(char c)
{
    SPDR = c;
    /* Wait for transmission complete */
    while(!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)));
}

void send_string_SPI(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != 0x00)
    {
        send_char_SPI(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

so now I have two strings which I want to send to **slave** one by one.

```
char freq_array[] = {0x01, '5', '0', '.', '0', '0', '\r'};
char volt_array[] = {0x02, '2', '9', '1', '.', '4', '\r'};
```

Main of master- ATMEGA8:

```
int main(void)
{
    SPI_Init();
    while (1) 
    {
        CS_Low;
        _delay_ms(10);
        send_string_SPI(volt_array);
        CS_High;
        _delay_ms(1000);

        CS_Low;
        _delay_ms(10);
        send_string_SPI(freq_array);
        CS_High;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Here is the main problem while I send only one array through SPI to slave I can get the data perfectly on **slave** side and further transmit it to the terminal via [UART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver-transmitter). But while I send both of the arrays, I don't receive both arrays perfectly. I rather receive one array most of the time and the other array sometimes. I want that the **salve** receives the array one by one. First, it will receive the first array and then again it should receive the next array. and should transmit it to UART simultaneously.

---

**SLAVE**

Slave initialization - ATMEGA32:

Here ATmega32 is receiving data using Interrupt

```
#define SPI_ddr             DDRB
#define SPI_port            PORTB
#define PIN_sck             7
#define PIN_mosi            5
#define PIN_ss              4
#define PIN_miso            6
#define SPI_PORT_enable()   (SPI_ddr &= ~((1 << PIN_sck) | (1 << PIN_mosi) | (1 << PIN_ss)) )

void SPI_Init()
{
    SPI_PORT_enable();
    SPI_ddr |= (1 << PIN_miso);
    SPCR &= ~(1 << MSTR);
    SPCR |= (1<<SPR0)|(1<<SPR1);       // divide clock by 128
    SPCR |= (1<<SPE);                  // Enable SPI
    SPCR |= (1<<SPIE);

}
```

ISR of slave- ATMEGA32:

Here I am checking for `\r` as every string i am sending from **master** ends with `\r`. So if I get `\r` I will set `spi_data_recieved` variable so that I can process it in `main` (i.e can send the received data to the terminal via UART).

```
ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{
    data_array[data_index] = SPDR;
    if(data_array[data_index] == '\r')
        spi_data_recieved = 1;
    if (data_index > 10)
    {
        data_index = 0;
        Clear_Buffer(data_array, 10);
    }
    else
    {
        data_index++;
    }
}
```

---

UART functions on slave - ATMEGA32:

```
void Serial_Init(unsigned int baud)
{
    UBRRH = (unsigned char)(baud >> 8);
    UBRRL = (unsigned char)baud;

    UCSRB = (1 << RXEN)  | (1 << TXEN) ;
    UCSRC = (1 << URSEL) | (3 << UCSZ0);

}

void Serial_Transmit(unsigned char data)
{
    UDR = data;
    while ( !( UCSRA & (1 << UDRE) ) );
}

void Serial_Transmit_String(unsigned char *string)
{
    while (*string != 0)
    Serial_Transmit(*string++);
}
```

---

Main of slave - ATMEGA32:

```
int main(void)
{
    SPI_Init();
    Serial_Init(103);
    data_index = 0;
    spi_data_recieved = 0;
    sei();
    Serial_Transmit_String((unsigned char*)"TESTING SPI\r\n");
    unsigned char copyBuff[10];
    while (1) 
    {
        if (spi_data_recieved == 1)
        {
            spi_data_recieved = 0;
            strcpy((char*)copyBuff, (char*)data_array);
            Clear_Buffer(data_array, 10);
            data_index = 0;
            switch(copyBuff[0])
            {
                case 0x01: Serial_Transmit_String((unsigned char*)"Frequency: "); break;
                case 0x02: Serial_Transmit_String((unsigned char*)"Bus Voltage: "); break;
                default: Serial_Transmit_String((unsigned char*)"SPI Data: "); break;
            }

            Serial_Transmit_String(copyBuff);
        }

        _delay_ms(10);
    }
}
```

**Expected output for this setup is:**

```
Bus Voltage: 291.4

Frequency: 50.00

Bus Voltage: 291.4

Frequency: 50.00
```

and continuous in this manner

**Getting the output as:**

```
SPI Data: 0

Frequency: 50.00

SPI Data: 0

Frequency: 50.00

SPI Data: 0

Frequency: 50.00
```

And in very rare case I could see the bus voltage.

I figured out there is some synchronization issue between the ATmega's but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of your code is you're transmitting simple arrays as zero-terminated strings:

```
char freq_array[] = {0x01, '5', '0', '.', '0', '0', '\r'};
```

there is no zero byte to terminate the string.
But the sending function:

```
void send_string_SPI(char s[])
    ...
    while (s[i] != 0x00)
       ...
```

expecting a zero byte to appear.
So, when sending the first array it will continue to transmit many many bytes out of the array bounds until there is occasionally a zero byte is met somewhere in the memory.

Also in the slave code, I do not see how `data_array` and `spi_data_recieved` declared. Are they `volatile`?
Also, looking at `Clear_Buffer(data_array, 10);` in the ISR I suppose `data_array` is declared of length 10: `data_array[10]`.
So, `data_array[data_index] = SPDR;` in the ISR can write out of the array bounds, two bytes behind it, damaging the content of the RAM.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and looking at the code and pointing out the mistake. Yes the error was in `send_string_SPI()` function. I have corrected it by passing the length of the array with the array and  accordingly changed the functions. And yes my `data_array `and `spi_data_recieved` was `volatile`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a communication protocol between them.

For example, for a college exercise, I had to create a [File Transfer Client/Server which used Vigenere Cipher](http://www.acarlstein.com/?p=891)

For each transaction between the client and the server, there was a confirmation.

For example:

If the client sent a command to the server, then the server would confirm that it did received it. Next, the server would run the command and send the data back to the client. Finally, the client would send a confirmation that it got the data.

Also, here are some links that may help you:

- https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/uart-communication-between-two-atmega8-microcontrollers
- https://www.instructables.com/id/Atmega32-Atmega8-Master-Slave-SPI-Communication/
- http://exploreembedded.com/wiki/Serial_UART_Interface_with_AVR
- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281509696_Serial_Communications_with_AVR_Microcontroller

Comment: I don't have the hardware or emulator to run the code; therefore, I am providing an answer with a post which contains code example.

Comment: As i have just started with AVR series mcu your code is bit complex. But the point was to provide an ACK which slave will send to master, after transmitting the data to UART. And master will wait for ACK. After master receives the ACK the master will again transmit the data to slave. I have tried this option but may be the implementation was not correct as I was not getting anything on the serial terminal. So my question is how to modify this code to implement such behavior.

Comment: My comment referred to the answer before the edit where you asked for clarification if he uses a protocol. I will delete it then.

Comment: @Osiris My apologize